# Ubunu failed to login to desktop and shows black screen command

Tags: command-line, 16.04, virtualbox, login

am a Mac user and i downloaded Virtual Box version 7, and SEED Ubuntu 16.04 works just fine, but after i logged out from system and came back again to login, it fails then it displays a black Screen command. What should I do? Please help me.

[first, i choose Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBJvZ.png)

[booting process, it shows failed oprations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Ue6.png)

[booting process, it shows failed oprations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAFZo.png)

[command screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2fxp.png)

*graphics controller in virtual box settings is set to VBoxVGA*

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Probably `sudo systemctl --failed` will return a lot of services with failed state. Did you fail to upgrade? Try `sudo apt install -f`. Are you trying to upgrade to something like 22.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you see are startup failure message for various services (ufw = firewall, AppArmor is a security utility from the kernel and keymap is for your keyboard).

You are in tty mode, which suggest that your VM could not load th graphics driver. Since you are in tty, after logging in you could type dmesg, which should output errors encountered at boot.

As said before, Ubuntu 16.04 lts is in end of life, so you could fix the problems by using ubuntu 20.04 lts or 22.04 lts, since it's a more recent OS.

Comment: thank you for sharing your answer, but i have to use 16.04 version, its required for my software security subject and SEED security labs :(

Comment: When using dmesg, did you see any errors?